# Powershell: update column value with full stop in column name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have a column named:   **10. London**
I need to update the value of this column using Powershell. My script works on columns that do not have a full stop (period) in the name "**.**"
The internalName does not work. How do I escape the full stop in the column name? I've tried variations e.g. $item["10'.'London'"]

```
foreach($item in $items){
  %colValue = $item["Title"]
  if (%colValue -eq "SomeText")
  {
    $item["10. London"] = "NewText"
    $item.Update()
    $List.Update()
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you get a reference to the field by using `$list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName()` and then there where you are updating items do `$item[$field.ID] = "New Value"` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding the period and space like this:

```
$item[10%2e%20London] = "NewText"
```